# HTML5 Canvas reset when adding to the body with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, document-body

So, I am currently working on an HTML5 game that uses a canvas element as a "point bucket", a visual gauge to the number of points the user has gained. But, something strange happens to the canvas when I add an element to the HTML document body

So, when writing to the body with javascript (document.body.innerHTML = "whatever";), the canvas will erase everything within itself and reset. Here is a quick and dirty example that I have whipped up to show you what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="a"></canvas>
    <script type = "text/javascript">

    function addToBody()
    {
        document.body.innerHTML += "<p>I am adding to the body</p>";
    }

    var can = document.getElementById("a");
    var con = can.getContext("2d");

    //Draw rectangle on canvas
    con.fillRect(0,50,100,100);

    //Add text to body after 5 seconds
    setTimeout("addToBody()",5000);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I know the traditional way to reset a canvas is to assign the canvas width like so:

```
canvas.width = canvas.width;
```

Is this another way to achieve the same effect or just a bug? Can someone give me some insight about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing innerHTML += something means that the contents are retrieved as a string, something is added to that string, then the whole lot is assigned to the body, whereupon (the layout of) it is all recalculated. (and event listeners are dropped - unless they're inline handlers)

You should use the object-oriented functions to do achieve the same. 
I.e

```
var newElem = document.createElement('p'); 
newElem.appendChild( document.createTextNode('I am adding to the body') );
document.body.appendChild(newElem);
```

This will leave your canvas untouched.